# CWAgent Metric alarms created using Terraform doesn't get data points collected (stays in Insufficient data)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a CloudWatch alarm for memory utilization using Terraform but the alarm doesn't move to `OK` state (stays in `INSUFFICIENT_DATA`). But when I created the same alarm with same exact configuration manually from the AWS management console it moved to the `OK` state and I see the data point.

I have installed CloudWatch Agent successfully in the EC2 instance that I'm trying to create alarms and I can see the metrics in the CloudWatch Metrics section.

My Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "memory" {
  alarm_name = "memory-utilization-alarm-${var.env}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name = "mem_used_percent"
  namespace = "CWAgent"
  period = "300"
  statistic = "Average"
  threshold = "${var.alarms_memory_threshold}"
  alarm_description = "This metric monitors ec2 memory utilization"
  alarm_actions = [ "${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn}" ]

  dimensions = {
    InstanceId = "${var.instance_id}"
    ImageId = "${var.ami_id}"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Project = "${var.project}"
    Provisioner="cloudwatch"
    Name = "${local.name}.memory"
  }
}
```

AWS CLI output from describing alarm created using Terraform:

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --alarm-names memory-utilization-alarm-dev
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1, 
            "TreatMissingData": "missing", 
            "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-west-2:289914521333:alarm:memory-utilization-alarm-dev", 
            "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-07-12T08:45:07.020Z", 
            "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-07-12T08:45:07.020Z", 
            "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", 
            "AlarmActions": [
                "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:289914521333:sns-topic"
            ], 
            "AlarmDescription": "This metric monitors ec2 memory utilization", 
            "Namespace": "CWAgent", 
            "Period": 300, 
            "StateValue": "INSUFFICIENT_DATA", 
            "Threshold": 80.0, 
            "AlarmName": "memory-utilization-alarm-dev", 
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "InstanceId", 
                    "Value": "i-03417f2d90d3dc6ca"
                }, 
                {
                    "Name": "ImageId", 
                    "Value": "ami-09d1383e2a5ae8a93"
                }
            ], 
            "Statistic": "Average", 
            "StateReason": "Unchecked: Initial alarm creation", 
            "InsufficientDataActions": [], 
            "OKActions": [], 
            "ActionsEnabled": true, 
            "MetricName": "mem_used_percent"
        }
    ]
}
```

AWS CLI output from describing alarm created using the AWS console:

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --alarm-names memory-utilization-alarm
{
    "MetricAlarms": [
        {
            "Dimensions": [
                {
                    "Name": "InstanceId", 
                    "Value": "i-03417f2d90d3dc6ca"
                }, 
                {
                    "Name": "ImageId", 
                    "Value": "ami-09d1383e2a5ae8a93"
                }, 
                {
                    "Name": "InstanceType", 
                    "Value": "t3.large"
                }
            ], 
            "Namespace": "CWAgent", 
            "DatapointsToAlarm": 1, 
            "ActionsEnabled": true, 
            "MetricName": "mem_used_percent", 
            "EvaluationPeriods": 1, 
            "StateValue": "OK", 
            "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-07-12T09:49:28.749Z", 
            "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-07-12T09:47:55.914Z", 
            "AlarmActions": [
                "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:289914521333:sns-topic"
            ], 
            "InsufficientDataActions": [], 
            "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-west-2:289914521333:alarm:memory-utilization-alarm", 
            "StateReasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2019-07-12T09:49:28.746+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2019-07-12T09:44:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Average\",\"period\":300,\"recentDatapoints\":[61.253520518958474],\"threshold\":80.0}", 
            "Threshold": 80.0, 
            "StateReason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [61.253520518958474 (12/07/19 09:44:00)] was not greater than or equal to the threshold (80.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK transition).", 
            "OKActions": [], 
            "AlarmDescription": "memory-utilization-alarm", 
            "Period": 300, 
            "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold", 
            "AlarmName": "memory-utilization-alarm", 
            "Statistic": "Average", 
            "TreatMissingData": "missing"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the Terraform code that creates the alarm? And what's the output of describing the alarm that Terraform creates and the one created by the console? You can get that from `aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --alarm-names [ALARM NAME]`

Comment: I have added the code here, earlier I was having troubles with formatting :)

Comment: `mem_used_percent` has an additional dimension of `InstanceType`

Comment: I have added what you have requested. describe-alarms for both alarms created,
is there anything else missing other than InstanceType?

Comment: adding InstanceType worked! @ydaetskcoR thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `mem_used_percent` metric from the Cloudwatch Agent has 3 dimensions: `InstanceId`, `ImageId` and `InstanceType`. The dimensions for each metrics aren't currently listed in the [AWS user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/metrics-collected-by-CloudWatch-agent.html) but you can find these out with the following AWS CLI command:

```
$ aws cloudwatch list-metrics --namespace CWAgent --metric-name mem_used_percent --query 'Metrics[0].Dimensions[].Name'
[
    "InstanceId", 
    "ImageId", 
    "InstanceType"
]
```

To fix your alarm you need to change your alarm definition to include the `InstanceType` dimension:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "memory" {
  alarm_name = "memory-utilization-alarm-${var.env}"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name = "mem_used_percent"
  namespace = "CWAgent"
  period = "300"
  statistic = "Average"
  threshold = "${var.alarms_memory_threshold}"
  alarm_description = "This metric monitors ec2 memory utilization"
  alarm_actions = [ "${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn}" ]

  dimensions = {
    InstanceId = "${var.instance_id}"
    ImageId = "${var.ami_id}"
    InstanceType = "${var.instance_type}"
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "${var.env}"
    Project = "${var.project}"
    Provisioner="cloudwatch"
    Name = "${local.name}.memory"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. I came across an issue where I spelled my dimension incorrectly using `InstanceID` instead of `InstanceId`. I was able to compare JSON output of a working manual alarm vs non-working TF created alarm which helped also.